# Hessian equals zero.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm currently just working through some maxima/minima problems, but came across one that was a bit different from the 'standard' ones.

So they used the usual procedures and ended up finding that the Hessian is zero at the critical point (0,0).

They set $x=y$, which resulted in $f(x,x)=-x^3$, which has an inflection point at the origin, which is the 2D version of the saddle point.

I have a few questions about this.

1. How did they 'know' to set x=y, or is this a standard technique for these problems? ie: Set $x=f(y)$ and choose some convenient $f(y)$?
2. In a geometric sense, what does setting $x=y$ mean? I'm having trouble visualising this.

---

[image: The provided solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set x=y means evaluating the function on the line x=y. put it another way, evaluating the function along the direction $\mathbf{v}=[1,1]^T$. Since an extremum on the whole must be an extermum along any direction,. If we can find a direction along which this critical point is not an extremum, then we can assert that this point is not an extremum on the whole.

Comment: Does the converse of this also hold true?

ie: Since we found a direction in which the critical pt is an extremum, then that point therefore is an extremum on the whole?

Comment: @Trogdor: No, a single direction is not enough(think about the definition of "saddle point"), but if for any arbitrary direction, the critical point is a directional extremum, then we can justify your assertion.

Comment: @RobertFan will this then also be true for f(x,y)=e^((x-y)^2